Disabling Windows 11 Presence sense
Some of the laptops under my care have hardware for Windows Presence / Proximity detection to see if someone is physically standing in front of the laptop.
We don't use the feature, and on at least one of the laptops the thing is malfunctioning and frequently making the Present / Not Present noise at "C:\Windows\Media\Windows Proximity Connection.wav" .  Bluetooth is not enabled.
The vendor HP doesn't want anything to do with it if I don't have the laptop on hand to troubleshoot, which makes sense.  Other laptops, including one of the same model, don't have the problem.
Is there a way to stop Windows from using this feature?  All I really want is to stop the noise.  I tried deleting the file but was unable.

Is it correct to assume that this is a business environment? Have you considered simply reimaging the computer? Deleting the file won't stop the actual problem, it will just generate new errors. What have you done so far to try to disable the Presence Sense system or settings?

Thanks for your comments.  The problem stopped, possibly related to attempting to delete the file, which remains despite the attempt.  For completeness, I'll mention here that none of the documented Windows Settings were visible for Windows Presence or Windows Proximity.  This is apparently not a Bluetooth technology but an NFC technology, which threw off my research.
